# Error when passing multiple tables from controller to view MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I tried to pass 2 tables from Controller to view by using ViewModel

I declared:

```
public class Temp
    {
        public Models.ORDER_HEADER_INFO ORDER_HEADER_INFO { get; set; }
        public Models.ORDER_ROUTING_DETAIL ORDER_ROUTING_DETAIL { get; set; }
    }
```

In controller I write:

```
public ActionResult DataLoading()
        {
            using (Models.AllDataEntities et = new Models.AllDataEntities())
            {
                var Odata = (from ord in et.ORDER_ROUTING_DETAIL join
                                oh in et.ORDER_HEADER_INFO on ord.ORDER_NO equals oh.ORDER_NO 
                                orderby  ord.TARGET_COMPLETION_FLAG,oh.PRODUCT_START_DATE
                         select new {Order_No = oh.ORDER_NO,ROUTING_NAME = ord.ROUTING_NAME,
                                     PJNO = oh.PJNO,DELIVERY_DESTINATION = oh.DELIVERY_DESTINATION,
                                      }).ToList();
                return View(Odata);
            }

        }
```

In view:

```
<table>
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++ )
{
    <tr>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(m=>m[i].ORDER_HEADER_INFO.ORDER_NO)</td>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(m=>m[i].ORDER_HEADER_INFO.PJNO)</td>            
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(m=>m[i].ORDER_ROUTING_DETAIL.ROUTING_NAME)</td> 
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(m=>m[i].ORDER_HEADER_INFO.DELIVERY_DESTINATION)</td> 
    </tr>
}
</table>
```

When i run the code, there is the exception like this:

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[<>f__AnonymousType3`4[System.String,System.String,System.String,System.String]]',
>   but this dictionary requires a model item of type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[TIS.Models.Temp]'.

When I debug, Data is completely loaded to Odata, but I cannot understand what type of Odata.

Comment: Try changing this - `select new Temp() {Order_No = oh.ORDER_NO,ROUTING_NAME = ord.ROUTING_NAME,
                                     PJNO = oh.PJNO,DELIVERY_DESTINATION = oh.DELIVERY_DESTINATION,
                                      }).ToList();`

Comment: @ramiramilu - Will not work as Temp does not have Order_No.

Comment: When I add Temp to code, they didnt understand what are Order_No, ROUTING_NAME, PJNO, DELIVERY_DESINATION

Comment: You have to use property name declared in Temp class. E.g. new Temp(){ ORDER_HEADER_INFO.Order_No = oh.ORDER_NO}.

Comment: Yea you are right, but the problem is that your Model expect List<Temp>, but you are sending List<AnonymousType>. So either change your Temp() to hold all the values or define new type and change the view to corresponding type.

Comment: can you please explain more about the solution Ramiamilu

Comment: Try this `select new Temp() {ORDER_HEADER_INFO = oh, ORDER_ROUTING_DETAIL = ord }`. Let me know if this works.

Comment: There was an error like this: The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery1[TIS.Models.Temp]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List1[TIS.Models.Temp]'.

Comment: Can you show us what was the type of your model in View?

Comment: I add .Tolist() then it works. But with this code ORDER_HEADER_INFO = oh, ORDER_ROUTING_DETAIL = ord . They will load all fields of 2 tables, is it true?

Comment: Yes, if you dont want to load all the fields, then you need to create your model with the properties you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have this select statement. Instead of Anonymous Type, Select `new Temp() { ... }`. Reason is that your View Expects `List<temp>`, but you are passing `list<AnonymousType>` from controller.

```
var Odata = (from ord in et.ORDER_ROUTING_DETAIL join
             oh in et.ORDER_HEADER_INFO on ord.ORDER_NO equals oh.ORDER_NO 
             orderby  ord.TARGET_COMPLETION_FLAG,oh.PRODUCT_START_DATE
             select new Temp() {ORDER_HEADER_INFO = oh, ORDER_ROUTING_DETAIL = ord }).ToList();
```

If you dont not want to use all the properties in the entities, then you need to create your DTO with the properties you want to use and map them in the linq query.

Comment: Will not work as Temp does not have Order_No or other properties initialized.

Comment: Glad my solution helped you. You can mark it as answer :-), if you think it solved your question.

Answer (score 0):

Your server side code should instantiate the Temp object while creating the list:

```
public ActionResult DataLoading()
{
    using (Models.AllDataEntities et = new Models.AllDataEntities())
    {
        var Odata = (from ord in et.ORDER_ROUTING_DETAIL join
                            oh in et.ORDER_HEADER_INFO on ord.ORDER_NO equals oh.ORDER_NO
                        orderby ord.TARGET_COMPLETION_FLAG, oh.PRODUCT_START_DATE
                        select new Temp()
                        {
                            ORDER_HEADER_INFO = new ORDER_HEADER_INFO()
                            {
                                ROUTING_NAME = ord.ROUTING_NAME
                            },
                            ORDER_ROUTING_DETAIL = new ORDER_ROUTING_DETAIL()
                            {
                                Order_No = oh.ORDER_NO
                            }
                        }).ToList();

        return View(Odata);
    }
}
```

Your view can operate on this list like so:

```
@model IEnumerable<MvcApplication16.Models.Temp>

<table>
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(item.ORDER_HEADER_INFO.ORDER_NO)</td>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(item.ORDER_HEADER_INFO.PJNO)</td>            
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(item.ORDER_ROUTING_DETAIL.ROUTING_NAME)</td> 
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(item.ORDER_HEADER_INFO.DELIVERY_DESTINATION)</td> 
    </tr>
}
</table>
```

Note: As in your original Temp object definition, you have mapped entity directly, LINQ will throw error as you mentioned in the comment.

> The entity or complex type 'Model.ORDER_HEADER_INFO' cannot be
>   constructed in a LINQ to Entities query.

You cannot (and should not be able to) project onto a mapped entity. You can, however, project onto an anonymous type or onto a DTO.

I suggest you create you modify your Temp definition and include properties that your want to send to view. That will make it a ViewModel object which is the right approach.

```
public class Temp
{
   public string ORDER_NO { get; set; }
   public string ROUTING_NAME { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I tried this and there was an error: The entity or complex type 'Model.ORDER_HEADER_INFO' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query.

Comment: Oh yes it is due to you are using entities into your model. LINQ won't allow it. The solution is, create a pure DTO object. I will update my answer to explain it.

Comment: Is there any way that i dont have to create pure DTO object?